# The loading bar doesn't show when using NuxtLink or RouterLink

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

If I use a standard link, the loading bar shows on each page load. If I use a NuxtLink or RouterLink, the loading bar only shows on the initial app load. Is there anyway to have it display on every page load?

nuxt.config.js:

```js
export default {
  /*
   ** Loading bar
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading
   */
  loading: '~/components/Loading.vue',
  /*
}
```

components/Loading.vue:

```html
<template lang="html">
  <div class="loading-page" v-if="loading">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      loading: false
    }),
    methods: {
      start() {
        this.loading = true
      },
      finish() {
        this.loading = false
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$nuxt.$loading.start()

        setTimeout(() => this.$nuxt.$loading.finish(), 1000)
      });
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .loading-page {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: #2CFFB7;
    z-index: 10;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: What is the `mode` of your nuxt project? spa or universal ?

Comment: It is 'universal' mode 

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom loading bar, you can manually control the loading bar at the appropriate position:

```js
const start = () => {
  if (process.browser && window.$nuxt) {
    const {$loading} = window.$nuxt.$root;
    $loading.start && $loading.start();
  }
}

 const stop = (abort) => {
  if (process.browser && window.$nuxt) {
    const {$loading} = window.$nuxt.$root;
    $loading.finish && $loading.finish(abort);
  }
}
```

You should call the `start` method in the layout component or other reused place to display the loading bar.

For example, in my project, a custom loading animation needs to be displayed every time an http request is triggered, so I added the start method to the onRequest interceptor of axios.

```js
export default function ({$axios}) {
  $axios.onRequest(config => {
    start()
    // ...
  })
  $axios.onResponse(response => {
    stop()
    // ...
  })
}
```